# `npm run build` error:Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I created my own template project based on the offcial webpack template, but I used webpack2 beta.25 version, I changed some conf to adapt to webpack2's new APIs,but I found when I run `npm run build`,the console will output error Path must be a string. Received undefined, I doubt that the code

`return loader + (options.sourceMap ? extraParamChar + 'sourceMap' : '')`

in the webpack.prod.conf.js leaded to the error if the param 'sourceMap' existed such as returning string like css-loader?sourcMap or sth else. I did not really find solutions to it, can someone help me? thx~ 
My template github repo is [vw2-tpl](https://github.com/libertyAlone/vw2-tpl)